# Java generics put-get rule

Tags: java, generics, collections

I hava come across the put-get rule when using generics in java, which states that you can not add elements to a

```
<? extends something>
```

collection and you can not put elements in a

```
<? super something>
```

collection. Now I came across the following code:

```
NavigableSet<? super String> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.add(new Object());
```

And I can not figure out why it does not compile.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example, a slight modification of your code:

```
NavigableSet<String> stringSet = new TreeSet<>();
NavigableSet<? super String> set = stringSet;
set.add(new Object());
```

This won't compile. If it did, this would be type unsafe:

```
String s = stringSet.iterator().next();
```

Because the compiler doesn't know whether the value of `set` is referred to by another variable with tighter type constraints, it disallows calling consumer methods where the parameter's type is broader than the lower bound.

To put this another way: the compiler only knows that `set` can contain `String`s; it doesn't know whether it can contain `Object`s as well.

Answer (score 1):

A `NavigableSet<? super String>` could be a `NavigableSet<String>`.  In this case, adding an `Object` would create problems, which Java is stopping at compile time.

The only thing you can add to such a set is a `String`.

Comment: (or literal null. You can always add null, at least from a type perspective; it may fail at runtime though)